# Firebase (Firestore) not saving data, but not throwing error either

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I am using React Native Firebase and react-native-image picker to have the user input some data, select or take a photo, and then save everything to Firestore.  I have print statement at the beginning of my handleCreateTool function, so I know the function is firing, but the log statements in the .then and .catch blocks never print, and the data is not saved to Firestore.

This is my handleCreateTool function:

```
export const handleCreateTool = (tool: Tool) => {
  console.log('Attempting to create tool: ', tool.name);
  firestore()
    .collection('tools')
    .doc(tool.tid)
    .set({
      tid: tool.tid,
      owner: tool.owner,
      name: tool.name,
      serialNum: tool.serialNum,
      imageUris: tool.imageUris,
      createdAt: tool.createdAt,
      updatedAt: tool.updatedAt,
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Tool created: ', tool.name);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log('Error creating tool: ', err));
};
```

And I call it here:

```
const handleSavePress = () => {
    const tool: Tool = {
      tid: '123456asdfgh',
      serialNum: '013SN568TGH',
      name: 'Impact Wrench',
      imageUris: [],
      owner: 'Timmy',
      createdAt: new Date().getTime(),
      updatedAt: new Date().getTime(),
    };
    console.log('TOOL: ', tool);
    handleCreateTool(tool);
  };
```

From this button:

```
<Pressable
        onPress={() => handleSavePress()}
        style={({ pressed }) => [
          { opacity: pressed ? 0.5 : 1.0 },
          isSaveDisabled ? styles.saveButtonDisabled : styles.saveButton,
        ]}
        disabled={isSaveDisabled}>
        <Text style={styles.saveButtonText}>Save Tool</Text>
      </Pressable>
```

I also tried calling it with

```
onPress={handleSavePress}
```

but the result was the same.  No errors, but no completion either.
I use the exact same function (just changing the collection name and the data) to save users, and that works fine.

I'd appreciate any insight here.

Comment: Instead of using variables whose names we can't see, hard code all the exact values that you're passing to Firestore, then show us the code we can also run for ourselves that duplicates the problem.

Comment: If neither the `then()` or the `catch()` of the write to Firestore triggers, could it be that you don't have a connection to the server?

Comment: @DougStevenson I edited to include the values.  I appreciate your help, let me know if you need more detail.

Answer (score 0):

It was a network error, even though my handleCreateTool function wasn't throwing an error.  When I went back and tried to run my Firebase authentication code (which I know works), firebase/auth threw an error

> Error: [auth/network-request-failed] A network error (such as
> timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.

I fixed it simply by closing and restarting the emulator, then restarting Metro and relaunching the app on the emulator.